# How to convert a dictionary of dictionaries into a list of dictionaries in a Ansible vars file?

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

Within an Ansible vars file, I want to convert a dict of dicts into a list of dicts that I can pass to an external role from Ansible Galaxy.

Input:

```
postgres_users:
  dc1:
    name: user_dc1
    password: pass_dc1
  dc2:
    name: user_dc2
    password: pass_dc2
  dc3:
    name: user_dc3
    password: pass_dc3
```

Desired output:

```
postgres_users:
  - name: user_dc1
    password: pass_dc1
  - name: user_dc2
    password: pass_dc2
  - name: user_dc3
    password: pass_dc3
```

Is there a simple way to do this within an Ansible vars file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`{{ postgres_users.values() | list }}`
 seems to do it.